# How to sum $\sum _{n=0}^{120}\:\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\:$ without the use of a calculator?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm learning about series and a textbook gives me the problem:

$\sum _{n=0}^{120}\:\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\:$

But I can't figure out how to solve it, what process to follow or formula to use.  I just know it diverges if it goes to infinity.

Also is it possible to compute the result without the use of a calculator (just by hand)?

*Tell me if there is any english issues in the post, I am still learning the language*

Comment: I've edited your post relating to correct grammar, I hope you look at it and see what changed.

Comment: Not to be That Guy...but the only english error is your use of 'is' instead of 'are' in the last sentence...you did well otherwise.

Comment: math has it's own use of the words  ( plus symbols) so symbols can get through the language barrier at times.

Comment: So many thanks guys! I'll keep in mind all the recomendations!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**HINT**

Notice that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}\times\frac{\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}} = \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} 
\end{align*}

Comment: so it equals 11

Comment: Thanks! 

I've been looking for the solution since more than an hour ago, but can't figure out what to do, all article or video that I see just mention how to solve when is raised to the `n`, but not when `n` is raised to a constant...

Can give me another hint? Maybe an example or a specific name of theorem/formula?

_(I just see that based on the answer is $\sqrt{121}$, but I don't know how to achieve this solution oO)_

Comment: You're welcome. Such concept is known as telescoping sum. You can find out more about it at wikipedia or wolframalpha, for example.

Comment: So you need to solve $(\sqrt 1-\sqrt 0) +(\sqrt 2 -\sqrt 1) +(\sqrt 3 -\sqrt 2) + (\sqrt 4 -\sqrt 3)+....... +(\sqrt 119 -\sqrt 118) + (\sqrt 120 -\sqrt 119) $.  Can you figure out what that is.

Comment: Oh!!!!!!!!!!! Now everything have more sense to me! In this case every term cancel out the previous one so the only one left in all the sum is $\sqrt{121}$ so this is the final answer... I'm feeling so stupid right now... 

Anyway so many thanks for all your time guys! Now is much more clear in my head!